# Subset/select columns from dataframe based on another dataframe

Tags: r, dataframe, subset

I'd like to select columns from a dataframe `df` based on their names with the help of another dataframe `dfkey` (but not necessary, i.e. can be transformed into a list etc.) which acts as some sort of key and has some of the column names of `df` stored. Example below:

```
df <- data.frame(matrix(runif(25), 5))
names(df) <- c("T1", "T2", "T3", "T4", "T5")
dfkey <- data.frame(c("T2", "T3", "T5"))
colnames(dfkey) <- "key"
```

The result should be a dataframe with only columns T2, T3 and T5 left.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The 'key' column in 'dfkey' dataset is `factor` class.  We convert it to `character` and then use it to `subset` the columns of 'df'.

```
 df[as.character(dfkey$key)]
```